# Is there an Excel formula with VLOOKUP in two columns

Tags: excel-formula

I wonder if there is a VLOOKUP formula that looks first in one column and if there is no match, proceeds to the next column and if there's still no match returns a value, for example, NO MATCH.

I've been trying to Google and YouTube the issue but couldn't find anything. Hope someone can help me here.

Comment: There is no basic formula that does that, but by combining basic formulas you may be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Question for you.  will the value you are looking for be unique?  IE it only occurs once in the two columns, or not at all?  If it occurs in both columns, which row do you want your answer from?

Comment: combine two vlookups in an if statement : if the first vlookup is false then it does the second...

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, if the value occurs in both column I want to take the info from the first column. The value may also not occur in either column.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, do you have an example of what your suggestion might look like in a formula?

Answer (score 0):

lets say you lookup table is is from A1:D6 with columns A and B your look up values.  And the value you are looking for is in G6

start with your basic VLOOKUP function as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(G6,A1:D6,3,0)
```

This assumes you want the value from the third column in your range (C in this case) to be returned because of the 3.  You are also looking for an exact match as defined by 0.

If the value you are looking for is not found in column 1 it will produce an error.  As such we can use the IFERROR function to tell us what to do when an error occurs.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G6,A1:D6,3,0),VLOOKUP(G6,B1:D6,2,0))
```

So in the event of an error it performs the second lookup.  notice the range for the look up starts in column B instead of A.  Also notice that Column C is now the 2nd column in the range so the 3 changed to a 2.  Now if its not found in either situation, we can simply nest the IFERROR inside another IFERROR as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G6,A1:D6,3,0),VLOOKUP(G6,B1:D6,2,0)),G6&" not found in first two columns")
```

This method will return the first value that matches your search criteria that it encounters starting from the top in column one and if that fails the first value from the top in column 2.  It neither is found it will post an error message.

There are other ways to do this especially if there were a max of one instance of the look up value in the two columns or if you did not care about columns and just wanted the first/last row (or nth row) of the occurrence.